# How to download YouTube auto generated caption text in PHP (other people's videos)

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

This doesn't work for auto generated CC

```
http://video.google.com/timedtext?lang=en&v=videoID
```

Example video-id of auto-generated CC

```
hf4lYSg1XpI
```

Example of embedded CC

```
xmkXlArEn-o
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this one instead of `video.google.com`

```
http://www.youtube.com/api/timedtext?lang=en&v=videoID
```

Source: [HOW TO extract subtitles from YouTube videos as plain text](http://mvark.blogspot.in/2014/01/how-to-extract-subtitles-from-youtube.html)

Comment: Thanks but that still doesn't work for auto-generated subtitles

for example, video-id: hf4lYSg1XpI
This video doesn't have a caption, it's auto-generated, so neither my link or your link seem to grab the auto-generated CC.

I tried your link, and it seems to be similar to my link. So it works only for videos that have CC embedded.

Answer (score 2):

The timedtext calls only work for manual uploaded or entered transcripts, and not for auto generated ones.

Answer (score 0):

Below the video, there is a button called 'more' (it's next to 'add to' and 'share'. Click it and choose 'Transcript'.